# What is infinity in complex plane and what are operation with infinity extended to complex numbers?

Tags: infinity

For a real number $a$,
$$\infty + a = \infty,$$
and if $a$ is positive,
$$\infty \cdot a = \infty$$

What is $\infty + a$ and $\infty*a$ if $a$ is non-zero complex number, where $\infty$ is real positive infinity?

Comment: For complex numbers, one doesn't consider "real positive infinity". One considers only "complex infinity", and there's only one of that, you have $\infty + a = \infty$ for all $a\in\mathbb{C}$, and $\infty\cdot a = \infty$ for all $a \in \widehat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: A nice way of visualizing it is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere

Answer (score 5):

I   agree with [Daniel Fischer's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585766/what-is-infinity-in-complex-plane-and-what-are-operation-with-infinity-extended#comment1236924_585766)

> For complex numbers, one doesn't consider "real positive infinity". One considers only "complex infinity", and there's only one of that, you have $\infty +a=\infty$ for all $a\in\mathbb C$, and $\infty \cdot a = \infty$ for all $a\in\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

but will remark that it's sometimes convenient to  describe half-lines in $\mathbb C$ borrowing notation from real axis: for example, $\mathbb C\setminus [0,i\,\infty)$ is the plane slit along the positive part of the imaginary axis. More exotic examples are possible: $[1+i,(3-2i)\,\infty)$ and so on. In this context, we are not really performing arithmetic operations with the object $\infty$, but rather use it as a shorthand for $\{1+i + (3-2i)t : 0 \le t<\infty\}$.

To some extent, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ also play this role on the real axis: they are not a destination, they are road signs that tell us to go in a certain direction and never stop.