# Show that s * exp (- s * inf) = 0 ? (s complex)

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, laplace-transform

Reading on control theory and the Laplace transform of the unit step function, I came upon the following in my textbook.

The Laplace transform defined as:
$$Y(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}y(t)e^{-st}dt$$

s being a complex number $s=\mu+j\omega$

Given the unit step function
$\sigma(t)=\begin{cases}
1 & t\ge0\\
0 & t<0
\end{cases}
$

The Laplace transform of $\sigma$ is

$$
Y(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}1e^{-st}dt
$$

$$
=-\left.\frac{e^{-st}}{s}\right|_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{s}
$$

My question is about the last part and how to calculate it step by step. I tried and did the following:

$$
-\left.\frac{e^{-st}}{s}\right|_{0}^{\infty}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}-\frac{e^{-s\cdot t}}{s}-(-\frac{e^{-s\cdot0}}{s})
$$

$$
=-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{s\cdot e^{s\cdot t}}+\frac{e^{0}}{s}
$$

$$
=-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{s\cdot e^{s\cdot t}}+\frac{1}{s}
$$

Since the right term is $\frac{1}{s}$, which is the end result, I
conclude the left term must become 0.

If $s$ was a real number I would have no trouble with this, but I
wasn't certain how to do this when $s$ is a complex number. Trying
with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%28x%20-%3E%20inf%29%20%20%20%28-1%20%2F%20%28s*exp%28s*x%29%20%29%29), it says this expression has value zero , but doesn't
specify if using real or complex numbers.

Comment: When you see $\infty$ there, you cannot just plug in $\infty$.  You have to do a limit: $$ \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{-st}}{s}$$

Comment: Thanks, I did the limit with wolfram alpha as linked. Also found this post which relates http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585766/what-is-infinity-in-complex-plane-and-what-are-operation-with-infinity-extended

Comment: You get limit zero here only if $s$ has positive real part.

Comment: How can we assume anything about s having a positive real part?

Comment: The integral definition of $Y(s)$ diverges when $s=-1$.  Try it.  So you can assume $\mathrm{Re}\;s>0$ or you can try something other than that integral.